# why global declaration of row and col not working in the below code

Tags: java

why global row and col not working but if we pass it as an argument working
but this is running fine if we pass index as an array 
here index[0] is specifiying row and index[1] is specifying col,passed as an argument

Not working version:

```
     package assignmentBt;
     public class SudokuSolver {
     public static int row,col;
     public static boolean isSafe(int board[][],int i) {
     for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
     { 
        if(board[row][j]==i)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(board[j][col]==i)
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
     int rowfactor=row-(row%3);
     int colfactor=col-(col%3);
     for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
     { 
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(board[k+rowfactor][j+colfactor]==i)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
     }

     return true;
    }
    public static boolean isfull(int board[][])
    {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j]==0)
            {
            col=j;
            row=i;
                return false;
            }}

    return true;
   }
   public static boolean sudokuSolver(int board[][]){
    if(isfull(board))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else {
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(isSafe(board,i))
        {
            System.out.println(1);

            board[row][col]=i;
            if(sudokuSolver(board))
                board[row][col]=0;

        }
    }
    return false;
    }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][]board= {{9 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,7 ,5, 0}, 
            {6, 0, 0, 0 ,5 ,0, 0, 4, 0}, 
            {0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
            {2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0 ,7 ,0 ,5 ,0 ,9 ,0 ,6 ,0}, 
            {0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,1}, 
            {0 ,1, 0 ,0, 0 ,5, 0 ,8 ,0}, 
            {0, 9 ,0, 0 ,7, 0 ,0 ,0 ,4}, 
            {0 ,8 ,2 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,0 ,0, 6}};
    sudokuSolver(board);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }System.out.println();
    }


 }
```

Working version:

```
 package assignmentBt;

 public class SudokuSolver {
 public static boolean isSafe(int board[][],int i,int row,int col) {
    for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(board[row][j]==i)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(board[j][col]==i)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    int rowfactor=row-(row%3);
    int colfactor=col-(col%3);
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(board[k+rowfactor][j+colfactor]==i)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
public static boolean isfull(int board[][],int [] index)
{
    int row=index[0];
    int col=index[1];
    for(row=0;row<9;row++)
        for(col=0;col<9;col++)
        {
            if(board[row][col]==0)
            {
                index[0]=row;
                index[1]=col;
                return false;
            }
    }

    return true;
}

public static boolean sudokuSolver(int board[][]){
    int index[]={0,0};
    if(isfull(board,index))
    {
    return true;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(isSafe(board,i,index[0],index[1]))
        {
            board[index[0]][index[1]]=i;
            if(sudokuSolver(board))
                return true;
            else {
                board[index[0]][index[1]]=0;
            }
        }
    }



return false;   

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][]board= {{9 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,7 ,5, 0}, 
            {6, 0, 0, 0 ,5 ,0, 0, 4, 0}, 
            {0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
            {2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0 ,7 ,0 ,5 ,0 ,9 ,0 ,6 ,0}, 
            {0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,1}, 
            {0 ,1, 0 ,0, 0 ,5, 0 ,8 ,0}, 
            {0, 9 ,0, 0 ,7, 0 ,0 ,0 ,4}, 
            {0 ,8 ,2 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,0 ,0, 6}};
    sudokuSolver(board);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }System.out.println();
    }


 }


 //is working}
```

it will solve the sudoku puzzle and give the desired out put of the puzzle,
this code runs on back tracking

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably is because, your global variables row and col are being used before and after the recursive call, and thus does not maintain its state while setting `board[row][col]=0;`.

While Backtracking, the value of your global variable does not maintain the original copy of rows and col, that was present while making the recursive call, but possess the last updated value from the last recursive call.

Thus, this piece of code always has updated value of row and column, rather than the original value with which `if(sudokuSolver(board))` was invoked.

```
if(sudokuSolver(board))
     board[row][col]=0;
```

For eg,

Consider the following program:

```
int i = 5;
public void recTest(){
i--;
if(i > 0){
recTest();
}
System.out.print(i);
}
```

Here output would be : 0 0 0 0 0, because the 5th recursive call to recTest() would update the global variable i to 0, and thus all subsequent backtracked print statements would read i as 0.

Now consider,

```
public void recTest(int i){
i--;
if(i > 0){
recTest(i);
}
System.out.print(i);
}

recTest(5);
```

Here output would be : 0 1 2 3 4, because the each recursive call to recTest() would update the local copy of variable i, and thus all subsequent backtracked print statements would retain original value of i.